# Posting API data to ejs using node-fetch

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I have been having trouble with displaying the API information that I fetched using node-fetch. I want the data title, img, and etc to show in the ejs body, but I receive an error message from index.ejs saying currentData is not defined.

```
var express = require('express');
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

var app = express();

//Port information
const port = process.env.port || 3000;


//tell application to use ejs for templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//make styles public
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
//return something to homepage
    res.render('index');

});

app.get('/comic', function(req,res){
    let currentData;
    fetch('http://xkcd.com/info.0.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        curentData = data;
        res.json(currentData);
    });
});


//index.ejs file:

<div>
<form action ="/dailyInfo" method="POST">
        <%= currentData.month %>
</div>
```